# Inspec title at the beginning in control rb files?

Tags: inspec

Is there a deeper meaning that in some inspec profiles a title is placed at the beginning within the control rb files?

```
inspec
 |-controls
     |-example.rb
     |-meta.rb
 |-libraries
 inspec.yaml
```

The example.rb file looks like:

```
# copyright: 2015, Chef Software, Inc.

title 'Example' # <- where will this title be displayed or shown?

control 'example-01' do
 title 'title for example-01' # <- this is understandable for me
 ...
end
```

Will this title "Example" be given out somewhere at some point?

Answer (score 0):

from [inspec docs](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/dsl_inspec/#syntax):

> In various use cases like implementing IT compliance across different departments, it becomes handy to extend the control with metadata. Each control may define an additional `impact`, `title` or `desc`.

the `title` is not mandatory, it is there to give an extra information.

Comment: This is totally true and understandable for controls. My question is not aimed at the title in a control, but rather at the title outside of a control.